# What movie is this?

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror, thriller

I cant remember the name of this movie but I remember scenes in it. I think it was a **horror/thriller and It looked like it was aired in the early 2000s**? **It's basically like the people get invited to this house for this survival game show.**

In one of the scenes one of the ladies who lost was sitting next to the pool with like a weight tied to her ankle and she gets pushed in, its later discovered that she was turned into food. Another scene was when the two remaining people is a man and a blonde woman and the man sacrifices himself and dies by being hanged.

After that the woman goes to a room and finds out the man who is running the whole thing wanted revenge because she had chose another man to be with instead of him. She then attempts to act nice and seduce one of the men who is helping the man who she rejected and she is able to escape.

There was also a scene where two people are sitting on a couch and a head of one of the contestants rolls toward them.

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions  or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. **You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title**

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like "[House of 9](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0395585/)" from 2005

> "Nine strangers - a priest; a dancer; a designer; an aspirant rapper; a former tennis pro; a woman on probation; an unsuccessful composer and his wife; and a detective - are randomly abducted, drugged and locked in a house by a wealthy maniac. They are informed through a public address system that there are seventy-five cameras following them, and only one will survive and win US$ 5,000,000.00 to keep quiet. The psychological game begins, with fear and greed affecting the participants."

There is also a scene where one of the [players hangs himself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_9):

> "The next day, the six remaining players find food and wine, along with a card that says "Good work". They run to Al B's room and find that he has hanged himself. "

Preview: